# How to check if a moving picture is touched to another moving picture

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def check_crash():
    (x,y) = c.coords(my_car)
    for car in other_carss :
        (car_x,car_y) = c.coords(car)
        if y < (car_y+ other_cars_height) and (y + my_car_height) >= (car_y+ other_cars_height):
            if x > car_x and x < (car_x + other_cars_width):
                c.delete(car)
                lose_a_life()
    root.after(100, check_crash)
```

Comment: What is the issue of your code?  Although I don't know why you didn't check the y coordinates the same way as you check the x coordinates.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas has a method named `find_overlapping` which will return all objects that overlap a given rectangle.